# Approximate the bilayer heat equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffusion, heat-conduction

If we consider a bilayer material the heat equation will be:

$$\frac{\partial\Phi_0}{\partial t} -D_0 \frac{\partial^2\Phi_0}{\partial^2x}=q_0(x,t)$$
for $0<x<s$

$$\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial t} -D_1 \frac{\partial^2\Phi_1}{\partial^2x}=0$$
for $s<x<\infty$

With the boundary condition:

$$\Phi_0(0,t) = 0$$
$$D_0 \frac{\partial \Phi_0}{\partial x}|_{x=s}= D_1\frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial x}|_{x=s}$$

and initial condition

$$\Phi_0(x,0)=\Phi_1(x,0)=0$$

The major problem with this approach is that it is very complicated to solve analytically

I was trying to approximate it by assuming the first fluency as a source term for the second equation such as:

$$\frac{\partial\Phi_0}{\partial t} -D_0 \frac{\partial^2\Phi_0}{\partial^2x}=q_0(x,t)+f(\Phi_1)$$
for $0<x<s$

$$\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial t} -D_1 \frac{\partial^2\Phi_1}{\partial^2x}=g(\Phi_0)$$
for $s<x<\infty$

With the boundary condition:

$\Phi_0(0,t) = 0$

and initial condition

$\Phi_0(x,0)=\Phi_1(x,0)=0$

How can I approximate in such a way to obtain a new source term?

I am using this approach so that I will be able to find a(n approximate) solution to $\Phi_1$ using the Green function method

What I thought was to use one of the following:

$$g(\Phi_0)=\Phi_0(x=s)\delta(x-s)$$ the source is proportional to the fluency

$$g(\Phi_0)=\frac{\partial\Phi_0}{\partial x}|_{x=s}$$ the source is proportional to the flux

$$g(\Phi_0)=D_0\frac{\partial^2\Phi_0}{\partial x^2}|_{x=s}$$ the source is proportional to the diffusion

But I have no theoretical explanation for any of that

Comment: I think you're short of two BCs. Your first BC is really an IC. Then each PDE needs $2$ BC (you have one 'communal' one) Also it might be simpler to assume the source $q_0$ to be constant over $0<x<s$ and $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: Re. BC, e.g. what happens at $x=0$: what happens to $\Phi_0(0,t)$, or $\partial_x\Phi_0(0,t)$ ?

Comment: I want $q_0$ as a function such that I am able to use solve using the Green function

Comment: You are right I am missing the BC $\Phi_0(0,t)$
I am not sure about the second one if I want to use the Green function